# spring mvc @SessionAttributes not binding properly

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Portlet controller like this. Here I bind a variable to Session. After that it redirects to another controller and renders the jsp .

```
@SessionAttributes({"attrName"})
public class Controller{
public void manage(ModelMap modelMap)  {
modelMap.addAttribute("attrName", true)
response.sendRedirect(URL_CONTROLLER_2);
}
}
```

So this redirects to another controller that renders the jsp.
In jsp when I do:

```
alert("${attrName}")
```

I get null.
Why am I not able to see the attribute.
Even when I debug and I check ModelMap in controller # 2, the attribute "attrName" is not present in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's an expected behaviour because `@SessionAttributes` are not shared among different controllers. Attributes saved this way will be removed from session as soon as next controller is called.

Comment: Thanks.but these controllers are sharing same session...so the attributes should remain. Just guessing though.

Comment: Did you read this: http://claymitchell.net/2008/02/11/spring-framework-annotation-sessionattribute-can-be-confusing/